# PHP Run Two Loops At a Time, then Iterate?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop, iteration

I want to run two loops at a time so i can use data from the first and data from the second loop, and then iterate:

```
$sql = "SELECT user FROM logins WHERE user!='SUPERUSER' AND user!='agata' AND user!='tomek'";
    if(!$result = $connect->query($sql)){
        return FALSE;
    }    
while ($rowV = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        foreach($argi[3] as $argvalue){
            $addtmpm=$rowV['user'];
            $sql  = "UPDATE `$addtmptable` SET sallary=$argvalue WHERE user='$addtmpm';";
            if(!$result2 = $connect->query($sql)){
                return FALSE;
            }           
        }
    }
```

That code just makes a loop in a loop. I want to update table, set sallary where user equals one from the previous sql

Comment: Where does `$argi[3]` come from?

Comment: @mario $argi[] is shortcut for $_POST['arguments'] which is two-dim array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do that by self by saving data from first sql to an array, than using it in the second loop